# yii2 - model load function does not set some model attributes

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I'm working on a PHP Yii2 application. I have a strange problem with yii2 `yii\base\Model.load` function. Here is my problem:

I have a form model called `PaymentIncreaseBalanceForm` like below:

```
class PaymentIncreaseBalanceForm extends yii\base\Model {
     public $amount;
     public $receiptNumber;
     public $description;
     ...
}
```

Here is part of my view file:

```
<?= $form->field($model, 'amount')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'receiptNumber')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>
```

And this is my controller action:

```
 public function actionIncreaseBalance()
 {
      $modelForm = new PaymentIncreaseBalanceForm();
      if ($modelForm->load(Yii::$app->request->post()))
      {
              //some logic
      }

       return $this->render('increase-balance', [
                'model' => $modelForm,
      ]);
  }
```

After submitting the form, I logged `Yii::$app->request->post()` with `die()` and all three parameters `amount`, `receiptNumber`, `description` exist in the post with their right values(every thing is right). But after calling `$modelForm->load` function, this is my model attributes:

```
$amount => 1000,
$receiptNumber => 887412141,
$description => NULL,
```

`$description` always is NULL! I don't know what is the problem with this field. Is there any problem with my code?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Probably there is no rule added for `description` attribute in your code.

Check the `rules()` method to confirm it.

As default, method `load()` applies only "safe" values to attributes and value is considered "safe" if there is rule for it in the current scenario.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Adding `safe` solved my problem.

Comment: Please see http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-tutorial-core-validators.html to get the meaning of the different validators you can specify in ```rules()```. "Safe" is a special validator (not even validating), for your description you could have used "string"

Comment: Please could you checkout [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42591365/yii2-model-load-does-not-work-as-expected)

Answer (score 2):

Similar problems often may be caused by ["safe attributes"](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#safe-attributes) (as say Bizley).

In complex cases with many rules and scenarios you can check current safe attributes via [Model::safeAttributes](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#safeAttributes()-detail).
Execute it immediate before loading data.

Answer (score 1):

Remove $ sign from description   `<?= $form->field($model, 'description')->textarea(['rows' => 6]) ?>` in view file

Comment: maybe mistakes on his code. waiting for his response.

Comment: Excuse me, that is a mistake in my code, I edited my question.